# AKKA 2.4.8 / Scala 2.12.0-M5 can't start system

Tags: scala, akka

I am trying to use Scala 2.12.0-M5 and AKKA 2.4.7 in a project.  But I get this error when I try so start AKKA.  I also tried using M4.

I am sure I must be missing something in my setup, as this clearly must work.  But this is pretty much just what I had using 2.11.8 - 2.4.6.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

build.sbt:

```
name := "AKKA-2.4.8"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.12.0-M5"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.akka/akka-actor_2.11
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-actor_2.11" % "2.4.8"
```

code:

```
package testing

import akka.actor.ActorSystem

/**
  * Created by on 7/8/16.<br>
  * <br>
  * AkkaActor demonstrates my problem when starting AKKA
  */
object AkkaActorStarter extends App {
  val actorSystem = ActorSystem("testAkka")
}
```

Error:

```
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class 
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Product$class
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at akka.util.Timeout.<init>(Timeout.scala:13)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$Settings.<init>(ActorSystem.scala:171)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.<init>(ActorSystem.scala:522)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:142)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:109)
    at testing.AkkaActorStarter$.delayedEndpoint$testing$AkkaActorStarter$1(AkkaActorStarter.scala:11)
    at testing.AkkaActorStarter$delayedInit$body.apply(AkkaActorStarter.scala:10)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:376)
    at scala.App.main$(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App.main(App.scala:74)
    at testing.AkkaActorStarter.main(AkkaActorStarter.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, that you are using akka for Scala 2.11 (`akka-actor_2.11`) with Scala 2.12. Scala minor versions are not binary compatible, you have to use the akka library that is compiled for your exact Scala version, 2.12.0-M5: `"com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-actor_2.12.0-M5" % "2.4.8"` or use `%%`, that will use the proper artifact according to your `scalaVersion`: `"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.4.8"`

Comment: I should have known that the comment I read (some place I don't find now) stating that 2.11.. was the basis for Java6 and 8 going forwards didn't mean to use 2.11 for 2.12.  That did just seem wrong.   Thanks!

Comment: had the same problem with play-json_2.11 and scala 2.12 -- a lot of libraries a lagging behind; watch out